# Cocoa - How To Format An XML File

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsxml

Is there a way that I can format an XML file in the proper way when creating it programmatically?

For example, if I use this code to create a simple XML File:

```
NSXMLElement *fallback_driver = [[NSXMLElement alloc] initWithName:@"fallback-driver"];

NSXMLElement *folder = [[NSXMLElement alloc] initWithName:@"folder"];
[folder setStringValue:[ads_make objectValueOfSelectedItem]];
NSXMLElement *filename =[[NSXMLElement alloc] initWithName:@"filename"];
[filename setStringValue:ads_driver_name_selected];

[fallback_driver addChild:folder];
[fallback_driver addChild:filename];

NSXMLElement* rootNode = [ads_user_printxml rootElement];
[rootNode addChild:fallback_driver];
```

When this is run, I would like to output to be as per the commented section in the image below, not the actual XML (that is not commented).

[image: xml code]

How I can format the XML file that way? Thanks!

P.S.

Thanks for the answer.. However, I would like to convert the NSXMLDocument that I have into NSData for saving...

I am trying

```
NSData *newData = [[ads_user_printxml XMLDataWithOptions:NSXMLNodePrettyPrint]XMLData];
```

however I am getting a warning that "'NSData' may not respond to '-XMLData', where before I added the XMLDataWithOptions it was working fine. I also tried the method 'XMLStringWithOptions' (as you stated - but figured that data was more appropriate), but the same warning was generated.

Any ideas? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can output a nicely formatted XML string using the following:

```
NSString* string = [xmlNode XMLStringWithOptions:NSXMLNodePrettyPrint];
```

Note that because `NSXMLDocument` and `NSXMLElement` are subclasses of `NSXMLNode`, you can do this with those classes also.

If you want `NSData` instead of a string, just do:

```
NSData* xmlData = [xmlNode XMLDataWithOptions:NSXMLNodePrettyPrint];
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. I have modified the original question a little bit.. If you would be so kind as to give me a further hint on how I can actually save to NSData, I would appreciate greatly. I should have mentioned that in the original question. Thanks.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Your edit to your question is correct except that you're calling `XMLData` on the result. That won't work and is unnecessary, because the output of `XMLDataWithOptions:` is an `NSData` object already, not an `NSXMLNode` object.